# Export Datatable to xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, ado.net

I have some `DataTables` that I want to export to a `xml` file. I can use `DataTable.WriteXml()` to output the contents of the `DataTables` to `XML`.

I need to use a `Response object` as shown. I need to add attributes to the root of the output xml. Please help me with that. here is the code which I'm working on.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim FileName1 As String = "Sheet1.xml"
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & FileName1)
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
    Dim ds As New DataSet("BuildingGroups")
    ds.EnforceConstraints = False
    Dim dtBuildingGroup As DataTable = Pipeline.Products.Components.BuildingGroupManager.GetBuildingGroupsToXML
    Dim result As String
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    dtBuildingGroup.TableName = "BuildingGroup"
    ds.Tables.Add(dtBuildingGroup)
    'Dim doc As New XmlDataDocument(ds)
    ds.WriteXml(sw)
    result = sw.ToString()
    Response.Write(result)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.0

Answer (score 4):

You need to get a `string` from the `XML` in order to use it in `Response.Write(result)`, here are some ways:

Suppose a small `DataSet` created like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable 
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1"))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2"))
Dim r = dt.NewRow
r.Item(0) = "Value1"
r.Item(1) = "Value2"
dt.Rows.Add(r)
r = dt.NewRow
r.Item(0) = "Value3"
r.Item(1) = "Value4"
dt.Rows.Add(r)
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
```

- You can use `GetXml` methods from the `DataSet`.

  ```
  Dim simpleresult As String = ds.GetXml
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  <NewDataSet>
    <Table1>
      <Column1>Value1</Column1>
      <Column2>Value2</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
      <Column1>Value3</Column1>
      <Column2>Value4</Column2>
    </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
  ```
- You can use `WriteXml` methods from the `DataSet` or a `DataTable` if you want to control `XmlWriteMode`. You get the `String` using a `MemoryStream`.

  ```
  Dim result As String
  Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
      ds.WriteXml(ms, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
      result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray)
  End Using
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  <NewDataSet>
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
      <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Table1">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Column1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  <xs:element name="Column2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <Table1>
      <Column1>Value1</Column1>
      <Column2>Value2</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
      <Column1>Value3</Column1>
      <Column2>Value4</Column2>
    </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
  ```

Comment: this is the most concise, helpful and perfectly written answer that I've come across on stackoverflow for a while.